# Should JavaScript/jQuery objects disappear when download hyperlink is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We use Atalasoft's web image viewing SDK to display TIF images in a web page. We recently upgraded to their client-side, JavaScript/jQuery based component and discovered some odd behavior. After initializing the control, if a link is clicked to a resource that should be downloaded, the control(s) clear themselves out. The issue exists in Chrome and IE 11 that I have tested.

Since it is a paid SDK, the easiest way to test this is to go to their demo at:
http://www.atalasoft.com/demos/dotimagewebdemo/

Once the page finishes loading, open a developer console and paste in the following (simply adds a download link to a file on their site):

```
$("body").append($("<div style='position:absolute;right:5px;top:5px;'><a href='/Gallery/WebViewingDemo.zip'>DOWNLOAD</a></div>"))
```

Clicking the download link will wipe out their controls on the page.

Adding `download` to the anchor tag resolves the issue in Chrome, but not IE.
Adding `target='_blank'` resolves the issue in both, but creates an ugly blank window first (that in my experience does not always close).

I am setting headers server-side to tell the browser to download the file rather than displaying it.

I guess my questions are two-fold:

1. Is it normal for JavaScript/jQuery based objects to disappear/destroy/whatever when a link is clicked to download a file or is this a problem with their implementation?

and

2. What is the best solution for this (preferably without the blank page showing up)? We need to support mainly Chrome, FF, and IE (most popular desktop versions).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the preventDefault method. https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: @dYale Except that it is just a simple hyperlink. Are you suggesting I add an onclick/preventdefault to the hyperlink or that there is something wrong with the SDK's implementation?